# How to restore Mysql database from .frm and .ibd files on localhost

Tags: mysql, data-recovery, database-backup, mamp

I have a VPS server that was hosting a WordPress that has crashed and I think must be deleted.
No backups were made. I managed to setup a rescue mode and salvage WP site data via FTP.

Because Mysql server cannot be started or reinstalled in this state, I cannot generate database dump.  All I can do is manually copy DB files over FTP.

The DB folder contains:

One db.opt file and many .frm and .ibd files.

If I zip this folder and try to import it into Phpmyadmin (MAMP), on local machine 0 tables are imported.

What is the way to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

PHPMyadmin can only import `.sql` files generated by `mysqldump` or PHPMyAdmin.

Your best chance is to remove existing `/var/lib/mysql` files and copy all the files that were in your server's corresponding directory.

Then you can try starting MySQL.

Remember to set up proper back up process and verify you have proper tested restore plan in place for future.